# How can i use different syntax highlighting for C++ than C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, themes, syntax-highlighting

I have two themes and one I use just for C# and other for C++, but I'm already tierd of changing theme every time when i want to program in other language, so my question is how to have different themes/syntax highlithings for those two languages, is there some extension or trick to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using RootSuffix. If you have same question do next: Find your Visual Studio shortcut (idk if it works on other version than 2015), right click it and on the end of the path after quotes add '/RootSuffix [ProfileName]' and change [ProfileName] with your name for new profile. When you open Visual Studio from that shortcut you will have separated settings, themes, extensions etc. If you want to get back just delete '/RootSuffix [ProfileName]' or simply make a new shortcut without it. Source: http://blog.slaks.net/2014-01-27/creating-multiple-visual-studio-profiles-with-rootsuffix/